# Logical negation, conditions on struct, mappings

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I'm still playing around with my first bigger smart contract, and I'm creating something like public sale, ICO, etc.

Now I'm at the point where I want to specify some conditions like:

- one address can participate only once
- maximum allocations, and etc.

My question is: what is the correct approach to implement such conditions, how to do some checks in my function before proceeding if I can't do logical negation on structs, mappings?

**1.)** I have declared `struct` with some data and `mapping` where I want to store my structs:

```
struct Investor {
        address account;
        uint invested;
    }

mapping(address => Investor) public investors;
```

**2.)** Here is my `invest` function where I want to deal with some checks:

```
    function invest() external payable {

        // Here I want to check if msg.sender already exists as an investor in my mapping.

    }
```

**3.)** My approach was just to check if `msg.sender` is in my mapping and just negate it:

```
require(!investors[msg.sender]);
```

But it doesn't work as I would expect from JS experience as structs are not convertable to type boolean.
How to deal with conditions like this? Should I just change the way I store my data?

[image: compile error]

### EDIT

**4.)** Looks like it's not working even with out negation.

```
require(!investors[msg.sender].account)
```

Is not working: "! cannot be aplied to type address".

```
require(investors[msg.sender].account);
```

and

```
require(investors[msg.sender]);
```

Doesn't work and code cannot compile with error:

[image]

Comment: This might work `require(!investors[msg.sender].account)`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, as I'm getting same kind of error but saying that negation cannot be applied to type ```address```

Comment: This should work `require(investors[msg.sender].account!=address(0))`

Comment: Yes. This working. Thanks. 

But what if I would have mapping like: ```mapping(address => uint)``` and wanted to check if some address is already in my mapping?

Comment: In that case, `require(investors[msg.sender] != 0)` should work. This is because, in a mapping, all the uninitiated indexes default to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll experiment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer so it's easier for others to find.

In a mapping, by default all uninitiated indexes default to zero. So does structs. So a mapping, to see if it's initialised, we can just check value. In this case, we can check the address and make sure it's not zero.

```js
require(investors[msg.sender].account!=address(0))
```